# Assembly.GetTypes() for nested classes

Tags: c#, reflection

Assmbly.GetTpes() gets the types in the assembly but if I also wants nested class (OrderLine) how do I do that? I only know the name of the assembly, not the class names so GetType(Order+OrderLine) will not work.

```
public class Order
{
  public class OrderLine
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, did you end up finding the nested types in `assembly.GetTypes()`, or were they only found by calling `type.GetNestedTypes()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if `assembly.GetTypes()` is supposed to include nested classes. Assuming it doesn't, a method like the following could iterate over all the assembly's types.

```
IEnumerable<Type> AllTypes(Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        yield return type;        
        foreach (Type nestedType in type.GetNestedTypes())
        {
            yield return nestedType;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
[MSDN has the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) to say about `Assembly.GetTypes`

> The returned array includes nested types.

So really my above answer shouldn't be necessary. You should find both `Order` and `Order+OrderLine` returned as types by `Assembly.GetTypes`.

Comment: This wouldn't pick up nested types within nested types. But really, who does that?

Comment: @Stefan - Detecting nested-nested-nested types is an exercise in recursion left to the reader

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
Assembly.GetTypes().SelectMany(t => new [] { t }.Concat(t.GetNestedTypes()));
```

Comment: Ooh, SelectMany. *rushes off to MSDN to absorb info*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LINQ statement. I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but you can do something like this.

```
Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(SomeType) && type.Whatever);
```

**Edit**

If the normal `Assembly.GetTypes()` isn't returning your nested class, you could iterate over the array and add everything you find in `CurrentType.GetNestedTypes()` to the array. like

```
 var allTypes = new List<Type>();
 var types = Assembly.GetTypes();
 allTypes.AddRange(types);
 foreach(var type in types)
 {
     allTypes.AddRange(type.GetNestedTypes());
 }
```

Comment: Nested classes aren't necessarily subclasses, and subclasses aren't necessarily nested. This doesn't do what the asker wants.

Comment: @Greg I was just demonstrating an example of a LINQ statement.